# Excel Data Model: Treat Headings from Different Tables as One

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

What I am trying to achieve is to have a single Excel file where two different users/teams drop data into a Table on a daily basis. This table should then create a pivot automatically.

The challenge I have is that I have created pivots from each table and added these to the Data Model. The tables share mostly the same data but for two distinct customer groups. The data model treats the field (CustomerID) as two different fields in my Data Model but I want to treat it as a single field.

I am maybe trying to use the wrong solution for my problem..

I want to take two tables -> single pivot where shared headings are combined so I can see a holistic view.

Is there any way I can 
(1) drag two fields into the same Pivot area but not have them 'group' or 'nest'
(2) get my pivot to recognise that the data model has shared headings across multiple tables and treat it as a single field?
(3) some alternative solution?

I don't want my users to have to copy and paste their tables onto one another.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should create a "collector" area for your data that combines both data and then make your pivot table based on that collector data.

Answer (score 0):

PowerQuery aka "Get & Transform" will let you do this quite easily. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164451/excel-indirect-function-to-read-dates-and-return-dynamic-values/47170312#47170312 that will walk through how to accomplish this.